# Does every real line bundle admit a flat connection?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections, line-bundles

Consider a three-fold intersection $U_{i} \cap U_{j} \cap U_{k}$ of a trivialising Leray cover $\{\mathcal{U}\}$ for a real line bundle L over a $C^k$ manifold $M$. We have $g_{ij}g_{jk}g_{ki} = 1$ and thus
\begin{align}
\ln|g_{ij}| + \ln|g_{jk}| + \ln|g_{ki}| = 0
\end{align}
Thus $\{\ln|g_{ij}|\} \in Z^{1}(\mathcal{U}, C^k)$. That is, this array defines a $1$-cocycle with coefficients in the sheaf of $C^{k}$ functions on the overlaps. Now it is a theorem that if the sheaf that the cochains take values in, admits partitions of unity, then the cohomology vanishes. That is, every cocycle is a coboundary so we can write
\begin{align}
\ln |g_{ij}| = f_{i} - f_{j} = \text{ln}(e^{f_{j}}e^{-f_{i}})
\end{align}
for a $1$-coycle $\{f_{i}\}$ on the open cover. Hence
\begin{align}
\ln|e^{-f_{j}}g_{ij}e^{f_{i}}| = 0
\end{align}
Now if $\{s_{i}\}$ is a section which gives a trivialisation over $U_{i}$ define $s'_{i} = e^{f_{i}}s_{i}$. Doing this in every coordinate patch we get that the transition functions with respect to this new trivialisation can be found like
\begin{align}
e^{f_{i}}s_{i} = e^{f_{i}}g_{ij}e^{-f_{j}}e^{-f_{j}s_{j}} \implies s'_{i}=  e^{f_{i}}g_{ij}e^{-f_{j}}s'_{j}
\end{align}
but $|e^{-f_{j}}g_{ij}e^{f_{i}}| = 1$. So the transition functions of any line bundle can be taken to be in $\{-1,1\}$.

Since the transition functions of this bundle can be taken to be constants  it is a theorem that the bundle admits a flat connection.

I don't have any intuition for why this result would be true. Is this result true, and if not, where is the mistake in my working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This result is true and your approach is correct. Not an intuition, but the obstruction of the existence of a flat connection is the curvature which vanishes here because the dimension is $1$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(vector_bundle)#Curvature

Comment: Thanks for checking :) Although, I don't think the curvature necessarily vanishes for a connection on a line bundle. I think it is possible to equip it with a flat connection from the above result though. With the set of constant transition functions above if you equip the bundle with the canonical flat connection in each trivialisation, the fact the transition functions are constant means this in fact gives a global definition of a connection, which is flat since the connection 1-forms in any trivialisation are 0.

Comment: @John117: You are correct that the curvature of a connection on a real line bundle need not vanish. Here is an example. On a manifold M choose an affine connection with Ricci tensor that is not symmetric. Such a connection induces a connection on the line bundle of 1-densities whose curvature is a nonzero multiple of the antisymmetric part of the Ricci tensor. That there exist affine connections with antisymmetric Ricci tensor requires some work; they exist on the two sphere.